# EF Core 2.1. Use custom database schema for migration

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, .net-core, entity-framework-core

Today I moved a project from EF 2.0 to EF 2.1.

I want to change default database schema from `dbo` to `MySchema`

With EF Core 2.0 I used the following code:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.HasDefaultSchema("MySchema");
}
```

But I don't see `.HasDefaultSchema` method any more in EF Core 2.1.

How can you change default schema in EF Core 2.1?!

**Note.** As the quick solution used Table annotation with each entity model

```
[Table("MyEntities", Schema = "MySchema")]
public class MyEntity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: @bommelding, yes. I have `using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's an extension method and it is still listed in the [2.1 documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.relationalmodelbuilderextensions.hasdefaultschema?view=efcore-2.1)

Note that you need the namespace `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore` and also make sure you have the package containing `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational.dll`

You may have missed the package when you were upgrading your project.

Comment: Thanks @bommelding for the answer. It works. My problem is that I store mine context in the simple library, but not default asp.net core application. Application's scaffolder includes `Microsoft.AspNetCore.App` meta-package, which depends on `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational`. But in mine library, I only added `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore`. After adding `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational` all started to work! =)